# Parsing closest brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I've tried to parse a LUA-File without any provided solutions (Why? Mostly npm packages needed binary files for that).

I have following variable with brackets:

```
configuration_options = {
    {
        name    = "RULES_ENABLED",
        label   = "Server Rules",
        options = {
            {
                description     = "Enabled",
                data            = true
            }, {
                description     = "Disabled",
                data            = false
            }
        },
        default = true
    }, {
        name    = "API_URL",
        label   = "API URL",
        options = {
            {
                description     = "None",
                data            = ""
            }
        },
        default = ""
    }, {
        name    = "API_URL_EXTRA",
        label   = "EXTRA API URL",
        options = {
            {
                description     = "None",
                data            = ""
            }
        },
        default = ""
    }, {
        name    = "Send_Password",
        label   = "Send Password",
        options = {
            {
                description = "Yes",
                data        = true
            }, {
                description = "No",
                data        = false
            }
        },
        default = false
    }
}
```

How i can parse the brackets correctly with RegExp or char-by-char parsing?
Best solution is, to set this to an JS-Object like:

`configuration_options: [{
      name:    'RULES_ENABLED',
      label:   'Server Rules',
      options: [{
          description: 'Enabled',
          data: true
      }, {
          // Other entries
      }]
   }, {
     // Other entries
   }]`

Here is my first try: https://regex101.com/r/l6YJ6U/1

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by parsing? At the moment it looks like you're just attempting to capture pairs of `{}`. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to parse the content of curly brackets, recursive. I need a `RegExp` to find the correct start and the end of the curly brackets. For sample `{ TEST }`: here i want `TEST` as match. `{TEST, { HELLO } }`: here i want `TEST, { HELLO }`; And the `{ HELLO }` will be parsed later recursively to generate a tree of these

Comment: What if a Lua comment also contains an unpaired `}` or `{`? Or a string literal contains it? Code cannot be parsed with a simple regex, it needs a more complex solution. Thus, your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm currently remove comments; These already parsed. I want only a solution to parse the content of the curly braces.